# Vector of Uchar to cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have an image which I am putting into a vector of `uchar` which I am sending from processor to processor using open mpi, however I need to put the vector of `uchar` into a `cv::Mat`.

Is there an easy way to do this?

```
cv::Mat image_on_proc = newpopulation(cv::Rect(0, start, population.cols, rows_in_section));
    std::vector<byte> img = matToBytes(image_on_proc);

    std::vector<uchar> test;
    for(int i=0; i<image_on_proc.rows; i++)
    {
      for(int j=0; j<image_on_proc.cols; j++)
      {
    test.push_back(image_on_proc.at<uchar>(i,j));
      }
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Send(&test[0],test.size()*sizeof(uchar), MPI_BYTE, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The above shows how I put the image into the vector and send it, there is a corresponding recv and it works, however I do not know how to turn it back into an image.

Comment: `cv::Mat imgFromVector = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC1, vector.data()).clone();` you can omit the .clone if you don't want to copy the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store a `Mat` into a `vector<uchar>` using:

```
Mat img = ...; // img must be CV_8UC1 in this example
vector<uchar> v(img.begin<uchar>(), img.end<uchar>());
```

and back into a `Mat` using:

```
Mat img2(img.rows, img.cols, img.type(), v.data());
```

Note that here you're not copying values, but just creating a `Mat` header for the data in `v`, so `img2` will reflect any change done on `v`. If `v` goes out of scope, then `img2` becomes invalid. You can simply use `clone()` to copy data, like:

```
Mat img3 = Mat(img.rows, img.cols, img.type(), v.data()).clone();
```